# <img> blinks when src change in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, image

I'm making a map that when you put mouse over a name in a list the `<img>`of the map change the src attribute to the map image with that zone highlighted, I only use the `.attr()` method of jquery to change it like this.

```
$("img.map").attr("src","newmap.png");
```

It works great in all browser but firefox, when the image change, first the old one disappear then there's a short time when there is nothing displayed and then the new image appears, how could I do this change smoothly in firefox like chrome or IE do??
(The time is really short but when moving the mouse through the directory the image disappear for the whole time the mouse is moving).
Or may be you know a better way to accomplish that effect. Thanks

Comment: Use [css background sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) for this. No preloading or javascript (for hover anyway) and they work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try preloading your images.  The blink occurs as the new image is being loaded by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `src` attribute has obviously changed. Well, the new image has not been downloaded yet. So it has to send a request to the server and wait for the response all while the `src` attribute has already changed. This is why you see nothing there for a bit. There are ways around this. In JavaScript, create a new image element with the new image as it's source. Add an onload event handler that will change the `src` attribute of the image you *really* want to show. Yes, this may be a bit more difficult the preloading, but it will decrease the initial page load time *and* it won't clutter your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head a combination of hover intent and a background image would help this.

The hover intent is good because you don't want to be downloading images unnecessarily.

If you give the containing div (or even the image itself) a background image of the original or last viewed image the flicker effect would be lessened. I suspect the load times for these image changes could vary so you could use this as an opportunity to show some sort of loading icon as well.

Having said all that I think it makes more sense to have the original image and then add a new image each time you hover an area. That way you can only add the image element when it doesn't already exist (saving http requests) and even do more graceful changes (fading over the original for instance)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the browser is downloading the image when you first reference it, and not before.

I'd simply have two image elements and hide/show them instead of changing the `src` attribute of a single element.